# Properly Reading a Char from an Int in C on a Stack

Tags: c, stack, char

so I'm having a crazy time right now reading characters off a stack. I'm storing the char as an int, so I can check for the EOF signal, but things aren't going so well. I'm new to the implementation of stacks, so things are probably just wrong somewhere. Here's my code.

I'm getting both the incorrect top character on the stack (it shows -1, which is EOF, instead of the last character entered), as well as some sort of memory error - "pointer being freed was not allocated", which references the destroyStack() function.

```
int main( void ) {
    int *letter;
    STACK   *stack;

    stack = createStack();

    letter = (int *) malloc( sizeof( int ) );

    printf("Please enter the letters, each on a new line, or  to quit:\n");

    while ( *letter != EOF || stackFull( stack ) ) {
        *letter = getchar();

        if ( *letter != '\n' && *letter != ' ' && *letter != EOF ) {
            printf("Adding %c to the stack.\n", *letter);
            pushStack( stack, letter );
        }
    }

    free( letter );

    printf("Stack count is %i\n", stackCount(stack));

    letter = (int *) getStackTop( stack );

    printf("The top char is %i\n",  *letter);

    destroyStack( stack );

    return 0;
}
```

and my stack code:

```
typedef struct node {
    void            *dataPointer;
    struct node     *link;
} NODE;

typedef struct {
    int     count;
    NODE    *top;
} STACK;

STACK* createStack() {
    STACK   *stack;

    stack = (STACK *) malloc( sizeof( STACK ) );

    if ( stack ) {
        stack->count    = 0;
        stack->top      = NULL;
    }

    return stack;
}

bool pushStack( STACK *stack, void  *pointerToData) {
    NODE    *newNode;

    newNode = (NODE *) malloc( sizeof( NODE ) );

    if ( !newNode ) {
        return false;
    }

    newNode->dataPointer    = pointerToData;
    newNode->link           = stack->top;
    stack->top              = newNode;

    ( stack->count )++;

    return true;
}

void* popStack( STACK *stack ) {
    void*   topData;
    NODE*   temp;

    if ( stack->count == 0 ) {
        topData = NULL; 
    } else {
        temp        = stack->top;
        topData     = stack->top->dataPointer;
        stack->top  = stack->top->link;

        free( temp );

        ( stack->count )--;
    }

    return topData;
}

void* getStackTop( STACK *stack ) {
    if ( stack->count == 0 ) {
        return NULL;
    } else {
        return stack->top->dataPointer;
    }
}

bool stackEmpty( STACK *stack ) {
    return ( stack->count == 0 );   
}

bool stackFull( STACK *stack ) {
    NODE    *temp;

    if ( ( temp = (NODE *) malloc( sizeof( *(stack->top) ) ) ) ) {
        free( temp );

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

int stackCount( STACK *stack ) {
    return ( stack->count );
}

STACK* destroyStack( STACK *stack ) {
    NODE    *temp;

    if ( stack ) {
        while ( stack->top != NULL ) {
            free( stack->top->dataPointer );

            temp = stack->top;          
            stack->top = stack->top->link;

            free( temp );
        }

        free( stack );
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: To format code use four spaces before every line. There's also a button you can press which will do this for you.

Comment: Yeah, I was missing the <pre> tag and it was messing up my formatting. I got it worked out.

Comment: Aye. The stack functions were given to me in the text, and I'm to use a stack for the assignment. This is my first time ever using a stack, and while I get all the concepts, I don't get why the destroyStack() call is raising an error, nor do I understand what's going wrong when I go to read from the top of the stack. I'm blocking spaces, the newline, and end of file char from being thrown onto the stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is with letter. It's only allocated once and when you push it onto the stack, it doesn't make a copy. That's why your top data pointer is always the last thing you pushed. Then you free it and destroyStack frees it and you get another error. Since the stack functions were from your assignment, the fix is to allocate a new data pointer inside the loop every iteration and ensure that it's not freed outside of destroyStack.

Comment: And that was it. I had the free( letter ) in there to free up the memory and let the pointer then be used for showing the top data point in the stack. I didn't even think about the fact that I was re-using the same piece of memory in quite a few locations, then destroying it and trying to read from it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well . . . it looks like you're double-freeing the data pointer:

```
pushStack( stack, letter );
...
free( letter );
...
free( stack->top->dataPointer ); //(in destroyStack)
```

So, I would start by removing the `free( letter )` line.

Comment: That won't work since each element of the stack would still end up with the `dataPointer` referencing the same address. It would still crash when attempting to free the 2nd element's `dataPtr` and only store a single value for all elements of the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Look at how many int sized pieces of memory you've allocated.  I think you'll need to allocate a new one for each entry you push onto the stack.